# Chrome: API for performance data

Tags: python, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

### Problem Descritpion

How can I access the data from the Chrome Performance tool either from the browser console or using Chrome driver methods when using Selenium?

In particular, I am interested in getting the **page loading time**. On the top diagrams I can see that the last elements were loaded around **1700-1800 ms** mark. The event log in the bottom shows that the last element started loading (and finished in a few ms) at **1720.1 ms** from the time the page was reloaded.

[image]

### What I Tried So Far

I tried using [Performance Timing interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming) like this:

```
console.log(performance.timing.loadEventEnd - 
performance.timing.navigationStart)
357
```

But I guess it measures some other performance. `loadEventEnd` and `navigationStart` have the most extreme values among the attributes of `timing` and their difference is only 357 (ms).

I also tried logging performance info using Selenium like this (took some ideas from [here](https://gist.github.com/axemclion/079f8bf1a997e9cfe9f0) and rewrote in Python):

```
import time
import json
import copy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

caps = copy.deepcopy(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
chromedriver_options = Options()
chromedriver_options.add_argument("--headless")
chromedriver_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chromedriver_options.add_argument("--log-level=3") # suppress selenium logging to stdout
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromedriver_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.implicitly_wait(8) # set timeout to 8 seconds
driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(5) # wait for page to load for the first time
_ = driver.get_log('performance') # discard all previous logs
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5) # make sure page loaded completely before writing log
with open('logs.txt', 'a') as f:
    for entry in driver.get_log('performance'):
        f.write(str(entry) + '\n')
driver.close()
```

The resulting logs contain entries with calls to `Page.frameStartedLoading` and `Page.frameStoppedLoading` methods and their timestamps and I had an idea to measure the time between the first `Page.frameStartedLoading` and the last `Page.frameStoppedLoading` after flushing the log and calling `driver.refresh()`.

Unfortunately, the resulting log file doesn't make a lot of sense. The performance logging doesn't stop (I thought it should since the web page is loaded at some point and nothing is happening performance-wise). If I call `time.sleep(5)` after refreshing, I would get some logs with 5 calls to each `Page.frameStartedLoading` and `Page.frameStoppedLoading`. If I call `time.sleep(7)` I would get 7 calls to each `Page.frameStartedLoading` and `Page.frameStoppedLoading`. And the difference between timestamp of the last  `Page.frameStoppedLoading` and the first `Page.frameStartedLoading` would be ~7 seconds in this last case which is clearly not what I wanted.

Anyone has experience with capturing this page loading performance info?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the **Performance Data** from the **Chrome Developer Tool** using **ChromeDriver** you can use the following code block :

- *Selenium-Python Snippet*

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  performance_data = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")
  print (performance_data)
  ```
- The parameters extracted are as follows :

  ```
  connectEnd                 Time when server connection is finished.
  connectStart               Time just before server connection begins.
  domComplete                Time just before document readiness completes.
  domContentLoadedEventEnd   Time after DOMContentLoaded event completes.
  domContentLoadedEventStart Time just before DOMContentLoaded starts.
  domInteractive             Time just before readiness set to interactive.
  domLoading                 Time just before readiness set to loading.
  domainLookupEnd            Time after domain name lookup.
  domainLookupStart          Time just before domain name lookup.
  fetchStart                 Time when the resource starts being fetched.
  loadEventEnd               Time when the load event is complete.
  loadEventStart             Time just before the load event is fired.
  navigationStart            Time after the previous document begins unload.
  redirectCount              Number of redirects since the last non-redirect.
  redirectEnd                Time after last redirect response ends.
  redirectStart              Time of fetch that initiated a redirect.
  requestStart               Time just before a server request.
  responseEnd                Time after the end of a response or connection.
  responseStart              Time just before the start of a response.
  timing                     Reference to a performance timing object.
  navigation                 Reference to performance navigation object.
  performance                Reference to performance object for a window.
  type                       Type of the last non-redirect navigation event.
  unloadEventEnd             Time after the previous document is unloaded.
  unloadEventStart           Time just before the unload event is fired.
  ```

Console Output :

```
Page Title is : Google
[{'connectEnd': 2725.146514015987, 'connectStart': 1503.1734234800108, 'decodedBodySize': 204837, 'domComplete': 7603.4821342458235, 'domContentLoadedEventEnd': 4588.4400826362535, 'domContentLoadedEventStart': 4576.987229310746, 'domInteractive': 4559.208601432438, 'domainLookupEnd': 1503.1734234800108, 'domainLookupStart': 1503.1734234800108, 'duration': 7623.300733238722, 'encodedBodySize': 61075, 'entryType': 'navigation', 'fetchStart': 1503.1734234800108, 'initiatorType': 'navigation', 'loadEventEnd': 7623.300733238722, 'loadEventStart': 7603.516579526861, 'name': 'document', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectCount': 0, 'redirectEnd': 1501.686197816412, 'redirectStart': 22.057947498907886, 'requestStart': 2725.729247123413, 'responseEnd': 3624.7713441197043, 'responseStart': 3349.3679493549, 'secureConnectionStart': 2049.7916668355165, 'startTime': 0, 'transferSize': 61926, 'type': 'navigate', 'unloadEventEnd': 0, 'unloadEventStart': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 3388.3040845619494, 'connectStart': 3388.3040845619494, 'decodedBodySize': 1730, 'domainLookupEnd': 3388.3040845619494, 'domainLookupStart': 3388.3040845619494, 'duration': 237.3373068328902, 'encodedBodySize': 1730, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 3388.3040845619494, 'initiatorType': 'img', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/doodle-snow-games-day-15-5907794870927360.4-s.png', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 3439.3892730100556, 'responseEnd': 3625.6413913948395, 'responseStart': 3625.271003314041, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 3388.3040845619494, 'transferSize': 2242, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 0, 'connectStart': 0, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 0, 'domainLookupStart': 0, 'duration': 230.20794413542762, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 3425.689371645131, 'initiatorType': 'css', 'name': 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 0, 'responseEnd': 3655.8973157805594, 'responseStart': 0, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 3425.689371645131, 'transferSize': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 0, 'connectStart': 0, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 0, 'domainLookupStart': 0, 'duration': 969.9734406621285, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 3502.3913129811713, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/createjs/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 0, 'responseEnd': 4472.364753643298, 'responseStart': 0, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 3502.3913129811713, 'transferSize': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 3520.930168473896, 'connectStart': 3520.930168473896, 'decodedBodySize': 12232, 'domainLookupEnd': 3520.930168473896, 'domainLookupStart': 3520.930168473896, 'duration': 134.0411771046674, 'encodedBodySize': 12232, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 3520.930168473896, 'initiatorType': 'css', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/2018/snowgames_bobsled/cta.png', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 3525.3821197382813, 'responseEnd': 3654.971345578564, 'responseStart': 3625.955856548778, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 3520.930168473896, 'transferSize': 12745, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 4527.024551785848, 'connectStart': 4527.024551785848, 'decodedBodySize': 842405, 'domainLookupEnd': 4527.024551785848, 'domainLookupStart': 4527.024551785848, 'duration': 2632.3253968704244, 'encodedBodySize': 265174, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 4527.024551785848, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/2018/snowgames_bobsled/snowgames_bobsled18.2.js', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 4528.843667863202, 'responseEnd': 7159.3499486562705, 'responseStart': 4946.163646693538, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 4527.024551785848, 'transferSize': 265741, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 4558.896162471504, 'connectStart': 4558.896162471504, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 4558.896162471504, 'domainLookupStart': 4558.896162471504, 'duration': 1005.3106518587082, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 4558.896162471504, 'initiatorType': 'other', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?s=webaft&atyp=csi&ei=N6mPWp6mC8H00ASJtoL4Ag&rt=wsrt.3384,aft.1175,prt.1175', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 4560.575876470308, 'responseEnd': 5564.206814330209, 'responseStart': 5564.1444075857435, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 4558.896162471504, 'transferSize': 358, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 4576.353841378264, 'connectStart': 4576.353841378264, 'decodedBodySize': 417606, 'domainLookupEnd': 4576.353841378264, 'domainLookupStart': 4576.353841378264, 'duration': 1903.6302084304214, 'encodedBodySize': 144417, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 4576.353841378264, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.smQ6-n1iGHA.O/m=sx,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/am=wCLkeMEAyP8JgogEKwgsQIpgGBA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oH8FZej9QmzW2qBqlOOQ7DASmnKAA', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 4578.110550711152, 'responseEnd': 6479.984049808687, 'responseStart': 5564.372556917789, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 4576.353841378264, 'transferSize': 144999, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 0, 'connectStart': 0, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 0, 'domainLookupStart': 0, 'duration': 574.9679253647753, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 4791.30009458269, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.og2.en_US.SpCLDXmWlPM.O/rt=j/m=def/exm=in,fot/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 0, 'responseEnd': 5366.2680199474635, 'responseStart': 0, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 4791.30009458269, 'transferSize': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 0, 'connectStart': 0, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 0, 'domainLookupStart': 0, 'duration': 1586.0147296126488, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 5417.5655534222005, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.29tAKSAI8cc.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IA/rs=AHpOoo82FxkTgGRAoVn-fgFU3zdQ5QIqEw/cb=gapi.loaded_0', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 0, 'responseEnd': 7003.580283034848, 'responseStart': 0, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 5417.5655534222005, 'transferSize': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 6646.626267079796, 'connectStart': 6646.626267079796, 'decodedBodySize': 83168, 'domainLookupEnd': 6646.626267079796, 'domainLookupStart': 6646.626267079796, 'duration': 783.8056119062338, 'encodedBodySize': 27299, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 6646.626267079796, 'initiatorType': 'script', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.smQ6-n1iGHA.O/m=aa,abd,async,dvl,foot,fpe,ipv6,lu,m,mu,sf,sonic,d3l/am=wCLkeMEAyP8JgogEKwgsQIpgGBA/exm=sx,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/rt=j/d=1/ed=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oH8FZej9QmzW2qBqlOOQ7DASmnKAA?xjs=s1', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 6648.111871788991, 'responseEnd': 7430.431878986027, 'responseStart': 7159.731278179281, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 6646.626267079796, 'transferSize': 27880, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 0, 'connectStart': 0, 'decodedBodySize': 0, 'domainLookupEnd': 0, 'domainLookupStart': 0, 'duration': 930.0310980101976, 'encodedBodySize': 0, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 6668.677730761095, 'initiatorType': 'img', 'name': 'https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 0, 'responseEnd': 7598.708828771292, 'responseStart': 0, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 6668.677730761095, 'transferSize': 0, 'workerStart': 0}, {'connectEnd': 7222.302954756732, 'connectStart': 7222.302954756732, 'decodedBodySize': 469, 'domainLookupEnd': 7222.302954756732, 'domainLookupStart': 7222.302954756732, 'duration': 208.68612730489625, 'encodedBodySize': 469, 'entryType': 'resource', 'fetchStart': 7222.302954756732, 'initiatorType': 'img', 'name': 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/2018/snowgames_bobsled/main-sprite.png', 'nextHopProtocol': 'h2', 'redirectEnd': 0, 'redirectStart': 0, 'requestStart': 7223.911346761861, 'responseEnd': 7430.989082061627, 'responseStart': 7430.7698479787905, 'secureConnectionStart': 0, 'startTime': 7222.302954756732, 'transferSize': 980, 'workerStart': 0}]
```

From this output you can easily pull out the *performance stats* of your interest.

Comment: This doesn't work that well; I tested it on a few pages from a browser so far. When calling `console.log(window.performance.getEntries());`, `responseEnd` in the last entry is always at least 1000 ms lower than the time when the last frame was loaded on the performance diagram (in the post's screenshot). Also, when hovering the mouse over the diagram, I can see how the page looks as time progresses. At time `responseEnd` (from the last entry) I can clearly see that the page is not loaded completely.

Comment: You asked a question about how to **access the data from the Chrome Performance tool** for which I have constructed an **answer** for you. If you see any deviation in the behavior you should raise it with **Chromium Project** for sure to help the community.

Comment: My question was about accessing data from Chrome preformance tool and **getting objective loading time** from it. In my question I actually access the performance tool here: `console.log(performance.timing.loadEventEnd-performance.timing.navigationStart)`. The time that I got from the performance tool didn't make sense, thus I asked this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have never tried to do this, and it's incredibly useful, thanks! Max, if you want objective load time, why are you jumping through so many hoops? Just track the time between navigating to the page, and when the last element loads. Done. Also, using WebdriverWait will avoid artificially inflating your numbers with time.sleep().

Comment: @Aphid I tried measuring the time between navigating to the page and when the last element loads. It get pretty good approximation of real loading time when doing this from browser console. For some reason when running same js commands from Selenium (with caching disabled) I am getting ridiculously fast loading times (10-20 times faster than what I witness when visiting website myself).

Comment: Contrary to the text explaining the answer, the code posted here actually shows an example using Firefox and geckodriver... nowhere does it even mention Chrome Developer Tools or the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on a Performance recording and select **Save Profile**. It'll give you a LOT of data, but should probably include whatever you need (it's the source data for the Performance recording report visualization, I think).

[image: save profile]

The underlying protocol that DevTools uses to get data from the browser is called the Chrome DevTools Protocol. Other clients, such as Selenium, can start a session with the browser (like DevTools does), and use the protocol to get the same data that DevTools gets. The underlying protocol method is called [Performance.getMetrics](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance#method-getMetrics). I'm not familiar with Selenium, but it should be possible to hook into the CDP, somehow.

You can also automate this with Puppeteer. I provide an example of using Puppeteer to access DevTools features in [Using DevTools Features Without Opening DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools-without-devtools).