# Measuring page loads programmatically in js

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, pageload, lighthouse

I'm a looking for a way to load a page (e.g. using selenium), measure page load timing and statistics on network calls. i.e. Similar information of what we could get from Chrome devtools network tab: request status, type, size, time, etc.

[image]

I have tried with [lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) using the performance audit configuration. But I found un-consistency between the report generated by lighthouse and Chrome devtools network tab, [see discussion on this thread](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/9205#issuecomment-502291102).

Is there js library that could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763303/tools-for-measuring-ui-performance/48763513#48763513) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938449/chrome-api-for-performance-data/48941918#48941918) discussion helps you?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, both links are helpful

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @DebanjanB for pointing out, I basically can get read performance data without need for an external lib.

```
var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {};
var network = performance.getEntries() || {};
```